# Compiler-RT CLANG LLVM

Tags: gcc, llvm, clang, llvm-gcc, llvm-clang

I have GCC 4.1.2 and like to build CLANG / LLVM using this GCC compiler version ony. I need source to source translation library so that I can modify my existing source code for some requirement.

Initially I faced issues regarding usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found during LLVM / CLANG make. So in downloaded and build GCC 4.5.0 and installed at a local path. I found that libstdc++.so.6 of GCC 4.5.0 has GLIBCXX_3.4.9 version. Since I wanted to compile using GCC 4.1.2 I set my dynamic library path as:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /local/gcc-4.5.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

And stated the make again after 'make clean'. Now that error did not occur.

However I am facing issues while compiling 'Compiler-RT' modules. I am not sure for which purpose Compiler-RT module is required but it seems LLVM and CLANG has compiled well.

Is it possible that I can exclude Compiler-RT from download , build and installation:

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
```

Build LLVM and Clang only

Is it right to set my shared library path to use libstdc++.so.6 of GCC 4.5.0 and is Compiler-RT is a madatory step to download and build it with CLANG / LLVM

I found this [sample code here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/)  - do I require Compiler-RT - I don't see reference to same but just wanted to confirm?

Comment: You don't need compiler-rt for source2source translation.